# Командная работа с Git на удаленном сервере

Tags: ubuntu, git, bitbucket

Имеем: 
Давнешний сервер на ubuntu на котором хостится множество проектов. До сих пор обновление проводились вручную, перекидывая файлы туда сюда. Разработчиков несколько, каждый может изменять любой проект.

Вопрос:
Хотим перейти на использование Git на локальных машинах и последующим обновлением проектов на сервере. Отсюда может и простые, но все таки вопросы:

- Каким образом осуществить этот переход?
- Как обслуживать сразу множество проектов?
- Как ограничивать права и доступ некоторых из разработчиков?

Comment: GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, Gitea/Gogs

Comment: @Alezzio Daid Читайте книгу: Git для профессионального программиста. Авторы: С.Чакон Б. Штрауб . В этой книге подробно все описывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую вам перейти на GitHub (Bitbucket). Если есть проблемы с доступом в интернет или приватность разработки, то установить GitLab.

1. Создаём репозиторий на сервере. Клонируем его на локальную машину. Заливаем файлы проекта. Коммитим файлы. Пушим изменения на сервер.

2-3. Инструмент типа GitHub (GitLab или Bitbucket) вам в этом поможет.

Comment: А если на сервере уже хостится довольно большое количество проектов, придется перезаливать каждый проект по отдельности? Или можно все же это как то более комплексно и правильно сделать?

Comment: Тут скорее больше суть в том, как на имеющуюся структуру данных\проектов(условно любую абстрактную) "натянуть" Git

Comment: @AlezzioDaid, один проект - один репозиторий. Если у нескольких проектов есть общий код, то общую часть можно оформить в отдельный проект как библиотеку. Сливать много проектов в один репозиторий точно не стоит.